# ZF2 form filters and validators. In which cases validators execute first?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-form

I have form in ZF2 with input text and file fields. The fields has filters and validators. In text fields filters execute first, in file fields validators execute first. Why does it happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ZF2, `Filters` are in general applied before `Validation`. Except, as you've mentionned, with the `FileInput Filter` which is only applied if `$form->getData()` is called.

The reason is that we need to make sure that the `$_FILES` entry is **valid** before we do anything irrevocable (moving the file into a storage directory, renaming it,... etc). For this reason, `file filters` need to be invoked after validation.